# Algorithm for reordering a table of items

Tags: database, drag-and-drop, gridview-sorting

I have a web interface that lists an arbitrary number of elements in a grid. I need to allow the user to reorder them using drag&drop.

The UI side of things is easy but I am having difficulty imagining what to do *on the database*. Here are the criteria:

- Elements are pulled from a database table
- Other than id, each element has a name and a field called *sortOrder*
- The name field is unique
- The *sortOrder* is not unique
- The grid is (by default) ordered by sortOrder first, name next.
- (Here is what complicates things) The user is able to edit the sortOrder value manually. They can use duplicate values, or leave it as default (which also causes duplicates)
- I can get anything from the drag&drop trigger, including the row number, the previous and next row number, the entities themselves, the *sortOrder* of the dragged entity, or the place it was dropped on. Lets just assume I have every data point I need about the event
- I want to make this operation with as few queries as possible

I could, of course, traverse the entire table, and automatically assign a new *sortOrder* with each loop but I feel there should be a better optimized way

What I have done is this:

- Get the dragged element and the current *sortOrder* of the element which is next from its new position
- Set the elements *sortOrder* to that of its new next neighbor.
- Update the table by incrementing *sortOrder* by **1** for every element whose *sortOrder* is >= dropped elements new *sortOrder*

This works fine most of the time, but when I drop the element between two elements with the same sortOrder, it moves to the top of the first one. not in between. So clearly, I have to factor in some other variables. But which?

### Example:

Lets say the grid looks like that:

```
|Id|Name |sO|
|--|-----|--|
| 1|Ape  | 7|
| 2|Bird |13|
| 3|Duck |13|
| 4|Gecko|13|
| 5|Fox  |14|
```

When I drag `Ape` and put it between the `Gecko` and the `Fox` I can update it to have *sortOrder* of 14 and then `UPDATE SET sortOrder+=1 WHERE sortOrder>=14`.

But this approach does not work when I drag `Ape` and put it between `Duck` and `Gecko`

Answer (score 0):

There are two sort orders you are dealing with. One is the number in the sO column. The other is the order as the rows appear. You want to maintain the latter, not just the former. So keep track of the order within a given sO value for Ids. If the sO of any next row is the same as the new row then you also increment its order-within value.